# React's setState() not working for nested DOM elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I added a button inside my react application ,which sets some state property. Code :

```
<button onClick={this.on} className = "add-button" >Add New City</button>
```

It works fine .
The problem is , when I paste this code inside some nested DOM element, like

```
<div><tr><td>...JSX...</td></tr></div>
```

Its not updating the store.I have also checked like this:

```
this.setState({ focus: true },() => {alert(this.state.focus)});
```

But it's not working.How to solve this?

Comment: You need to be more specific with what you've tried so far. Do you know for sure that your `this.on` function is running at all? If it is in fact running, are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: Post your entire component

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xVscutTy     -- link to entire component code .   Please skip {index} variable.Just typo error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a click handler in the parent `table` element and child `button`. When you click the button the `click` event is going to be propagated to the parent and switch focus back to false.

You can change this behavior by using `event.stopPropagation` in the parent.

```js
class Legs extends React.Component {
  state = { focus: false ,index: null }
    
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.on = this.on.bind(this);
    this.off = this.off.bind(this);
  }

 on(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.setState({ focus: true }, console.log("Focus"))  
  }

  off() {  
    this.setState({ focus: false }, console.log("Off") ); 
  }

 render () {

  return (
   <div> 
         <table className="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table " onClick={this.off}>
     <thead >
      <tr >
       <th >City</th>
       <th>No. Of Nights</th>
       <th></th>
       <th></th>
      </tr>
     </thead>

     <tbody>
      {
       this.props.legs.map ( (leg,index) => {
        return (
         <tr key ={index} >                     
                    <td>{leg}</td>
          <td><button className="material-icons" onClick = {this.on}>mode_edit</button></td>
          
         </tr>
        );
       }) 
      }
      
     </tbody>
    </table>
               
       </div>
  );
 }

}

ReactDOM.render(<Legs legs={['l1','l2']}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Working now.Perfect answer. Thanks man! Not aware of this concept :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sample code. It seems to change the state according to your code structure.

Are you having a problem in toggling the state value from true to false or vice versa?

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {focus: false};
    this.on  = this.on.bind(this);
  }

  on(){
    console.log("Intial State Value" ,this.state);
    this.setState({focus : !this.state.focus},() => (console.log("Changed State Value",this.state)));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <button onClick={this.on} className = "add-button" >Add New City</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app' />
```

Comment: Are you having a problem in toggling the state value from true to false or vice versa?   ----- YES             https://pastebin.com/xVscutTy    --- you can see my component code here .Please skip {index} variable.Just typo error

Comment: @KushagraKumarRai - Updated the snippet to toggle from true to false and vice versa. Try running above snippet

Comment: @ HarshMakadia   - I think the problem arises when I put the button inside map() function, not due to nesting.I am still not able to figure out why inside map() function it is happening.I have also bind the map to this.

Comment: Can you try changing it to onClick = {() => this.on()} and see if it works for you.

Comment: Working now. It is due to the fact that child button's event propagates to parents' event . I used  event.stopPropagation(); to stop the behaviour. Thanks :)

Comment: @KushagraKumarRai - Nice!